# Call NextJs Route and pass data to component

Tags: javascript, next.js, puppeteer, vercel

I have a NextJs application with an api route, which calls an internal page to generate a pdf file.

This method generate the pdf file in my API route:

```
function serialize(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for (var p in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    }
  return str.join("&");
};

async function generatePdf(body) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Allows you to intercept a request; must appear before
  // your first page.goto()
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);

  // Request intercept handler... will be triggered with
  // each page.goto() statement
  page.on("request", (interceptedRequest) => {
    // Here, is where you change the request method and
    // add your post data
    var data = {
      method: "POST",
      postData: serialize(body),
      headers: {
        ...interceptedRequest.headers(),
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
    };

    // Request modified... finish sending!
    interceptedRequest.continue(data);

    // Immediately disable setRequestInterception, or all other requests will hang
    page.setRequestInterception(false);
  });

  const response = await page.goto(process.env.GEN_PDF_URL, {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });

  const pdf = await page.pdf({
    path: "test.pdf",
    printBackground: true,
    format: "a4",
  });
  const responseBody = await response.text();
  console.log(responseBody);
  await browser.close();

  return pdf;
}
```

This method (sendEmail) is being called from the frontend, with the data (req.body) provided to generate the pdf page properly. I am passing that data as a parameter to the `generatePdf` method.

```
async function sendEmail(req, res) {
  const pdf = await generatePdf(req.body);
  ...
```

I am wondering if it is possible to generate that page using the provider data from the req.body in nextjs. So that I can generate the pdf files dynamically since the content of the Pdf page changes depending on what data I sent.

Comment: Yes you can generate a PDF in your API route. I'm unsure where you need help now though

Comment: @Dominik I am using a  Page component for that generation in which I want to update a few part which dynamic data, which shall be sent by the puppeteer request, but how can I access that to dynamically generate that pdf? I am able to generate a pdf but not with dynamic date from puppeteer. Do you understand my issue? :)

Comment: So you're asking how to send data to your API route so it can take that data to generate your PDF dynamically?

Comment: @Dominik the api route in this case the sendEmail() and generatePdf() already contain the proper data, which is req.body, I want that data passed down to the Page component I go to using puppeteer, so I can use that data in the Page component which I refer to, to generate the dynamic content

Comment: Wait... you're running puppeteer in the front end? Why? Hwy are you not generating the PDF in the API route? I'm super confused

Comment: no I am using puppeteer in the api route, my frontend just calls the API route

Comment: @utdev did you figure a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case, with the need to **render** a Next page from a third-party **POST** call.
If someone still wonders if this is possible, the answer is yes.

Use `getServerSideProps` as follows:

```js
import { parseBody } from 'next/dist/server/api-utils/node';

export default function MyComponent({ body }) {
  // do stuff with body
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {
  return {
    props: { body: await parseBody(req) },
  };
};
```

You can't do it using Next.js 13+ `app` dir, but [using both pages/ and app/ in production together is supported and encouraged](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/41745#discussioncomment-5809024).